How can you tell if an exponential function has undergone transformations from a table?
Here's a scenario. Say there are three points on a table: $(0,1.5)$, $(1,3)$, and $(2,6)$. The equation for the exponential function modeled by these points is $y=a\times b^{x-1}$. However, after solving for the equation, I came out with the function of $y=1.5\times 2^x$, which models the parent function. I understand this is the same thing, but in this case, how can we tell if an equation has been transformed?
To add to this, I am unsure of how to convert points on a table to the equation of a transformed exponential function. If the points were $(0,4)$, $(1,7)$, and $(2,13)$, it is obvious that this exponential function has been transformed. The answer to this problem is obvious, but say there was a more complicated transformation than the one above. How would we write an equation for it? I'm sorry if this question is basic, but I am taking Algebra 1 right now and we are covering a unit on writing equations for linear, exponential, and quadratic functions. Thank you.

$1.5 \times 2^x = 3 \times 2^{x-1}$ but I am not sure why you have a distinction here.  Meanwhile $y = a , b^x$ is equivalent to $\log(y)=\log(a)+x \log(b)$ at least when $a, b$ and all the $y$s are positive

I suspect the question gave the exponent as $x-1$ which means there is only one solution $(a,b)$ that works.

Consider the graph with equation $y=3\times 2^{x}$
If we dilate the graph by factor $\frac{1}{2}$ from the $x$-axis it becomes $y=1.5\times 2^x$.
If we translate the graph 1 unit right it becomes $y=3\times 2^{x-1}$
However, if you draw both graphs you will see they are the same picture?
Why?
Because (as another commenter has pointed out): $2^{x-1}=\frac{1}{2}\times 2^{x}$ and so $3\times 2^{x-1}=1.5\times 2^x$ for all $x$
Same graph, different equation. Two different types of transformation, same result.
Since there are two parameters in the equation $y=a\times b^{x-1}$, two points are sufficient to uniquely determine $a$ and $b$. However, for this to work (and to be unique), the exponent must remain $x-1$.
Hope this helps.
